# Return of the lost ant 3D

Tags: optimization, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Starting in the center of a sphere of radius 1, draw a path with the shortest possible length that intersects every plane that is tangent to the sphere.

This question appeared as a generalization of [the recently considered problem of the lost ant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604824/can-this-ant-find-its-way-back-to-the-nest)

> Starting in the center of a circle of radius 40 ft, draw a path with the shortest possible length that intersects every line that is tangent to the circle.

to the third dimension.

Comment: This question looks much harder even than that one, and that one was only answered by reference to a paper in French (as I recall)!

Comment: @dfeuer It's harder to get an exact solution of this problem but I hope it would be easy enough to get some approximate solutions.

Comment: My bet is that the solution will start with a straight segment exiting the sphere (of course) and then spiral around toward somewhere near the opposite pole, probably doing something a bit funky at each end. I have no clue what sort of spiral that will be, exactly. Coming up with a way to calculate whether a given path offers enough coverage seems tricky (when considering computational approaches).

Comment: Well geez. Why not an $n$-sphere, while we're at it?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber - sounds like you've got another thesis topic :)

Comment: @dfeuer A spiral between two poles is a good idea for rather short path. My solution is much easier but it gives the paths which are not short enough.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I know solution which is suitable for $n$-dimensional generalization of this problem but it doesn't give the path with the minimal length...

Comment: Constructor, why don't you reveal what you've found?

Comment: @dfeuer I hoped that someone would be able to find a much better solution than my own one. Should I add it to the answer?

Comment: @Constructor, you should of course. By the way, something about the sort of spiral I'm envisioning seems suspiciously familiar, like I've seen it presented as the solution to some problem before, but I can't remember the context.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to your question, but doesn't a sphere have infinitely many tangential planes? This is true about a circle and tangent lines, but how to you walk the surface area of a sphere? This will take a path that is infinitely long, unless you assign a width for the ant's path.

Comment: That [such paths exist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) isn't an problem. Whether or not they have a length is another matter.