# Lost in a Forest Problem 3d Verision: Point and Plane

Tags: geometry, optimization, searching

The [lost in a forest problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%27s_lost_in_a_forest_problem) is famous, specifically see [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604824/can-this-ant-find-its-way-back-to-the-nest).  The problem takes place in the plane.  Consider the following 3d version.  There is a point $p \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and a plane $P$  which is unit distance from $p$.  **My question**: What is the minimum length (rectifiable) curve $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which starts at $p$, and such that all rotations of $C$ about $p$ intersect $P$?  (Of course, rotations are elements of $SO(3)$.)

I suspect a minimum length curve actually exists, because we can bound it from above.  For example, let $r>1$ and consider the curve consisting of a radius of length $r$ from $p$ together with two circles $C_1, C_2$ of radii $r$ centered at $p$ such that $C_1$ intersects $C_2$ at a right angle.  For sufficiently large $r>1$, it is clear that all rotations of this curve intersect $P$.

**My second question:** What about the problem in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in which we replace the plane $P$ with a line $\ell$ unit distance from $p$.  This is exactly the lost in a forest problem but in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Is there a minimum length curve for this problem, and if so what is it?  I suspect that there does not exist a rectifiable curve $C$ starting at $p$ such that all rotations of it intersect $\ell$.  Can this be proven (or disproven)?

I am not sure if these problems have been studied (I know related problems have been).  If so, can anybody point me to a reference?  Thank you.